# Beginner in Java - Relations and other questions about specific code

Tags: java, relationship, super, relation

Okay, so what I need help with is the relations between the classes and the methods. I've heard about association and aggregation, but I don't know how to use them, or even if they fit in this code.

Also, I would like to know what `super()` does and what does `p3=p3In` in `class Pgm2`.

```
public class Pgm1 { 

    public Pgm1() { 
        System.out.println("Konstruktor Pgm1"); 
    } 

    public void skriv() { 
        System.out.println("Skriv i Pgm1"); 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Pgm3 p3=new Pgm3(); 
        p3.skriv(); 
        Pgm4 p4=new Pgm4(p3); 
        p4.skriv(); 
        Pgm2 p2=new Pgm2(); 
        p2.skriv(); 
    } 

} 

public class Pgm2 { 

    private Pgm1 p1; 

    public Pgm2() { 
        p1=new Pgm1(); 
        System.out.println("Konstruktor Pgm2"); 
    } 

    public void skriv() { 
        System.out.println("Skriv i Pgm2"); 
    } 

} 

public class Pgm3 { 

    public Pgm3() { 
        System.out.println("Konstruktor Pgm3"); 
    } 

    public void skriv() { 
        System.out.println("Skriv i Pgm3"); 
    } 

} 

public class Pgm4 extends Pgm2 { 

    private Pgm3 p3; 

    public Pgm4(Pgm3 p3In) { 
        super(); 
        p3=p3In; 
        System.out.println("Konstruktor Pgm4"); 
    } 

    public void skriv() { 
        System.out.println("Skriv i Pgm4"); 
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classes `Pgm1`, `Pgm2` and `Pgm3` are all pretty normal classes. However the class `Pgm4` *Extends* `Pgm2` meaning that `Pgm4` is a child class of `Pgm2`. Think of  this like a zoo simulator program, you may have one class that is called `Animal` or something similar, and then a lot of other classes that extend it. Some examples of these classes might me `Lion`, `Tiger`, `Bear` (Oh my) and each of those specific animal classes are animals in the simulator.

The `super();` statement (like others have pointed out) calls the constructor of the class that you extend. Finally the `p3=p3In;` line assigns a variable inside the `Pgm4` class to whatever is passed to the class through the constructor. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

`super();` calls constructor (without parameters) of base class (in this case, `Pgm2`).

`p3=p3In;` assigns value of `p3In` to class variable `p3`.

Answer (score 0):

```
super()
```

is a special use of the super keyword where you call a parameterless parent constructor. In general, the super keyword can be used to call overridden methods, access hidden fields or invoke a superclass's constructor.